# How to Insert multiple data in django to django form?

Tags: python, django

I want to insert multiple row into my database from form2. Below are my codes

first model.py

```
class DataPribadiSiswa(models.Model):
   SiswaID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
   WaliKelasID=models.CharField(max_length=5,blank=True,null=True)
```

second model.py

```
class RiwayatSekolah(models.Model):
   SekolahID=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
   SiswaID_FK=models.ForeignKey(DataPribadiSiswa,blank=True, null=True)
   SekolahNama=models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True,null=True)
   SekolahThMasuk=models.CharField(max_length=4,blank=True,null=True)
   SekolahThKeluar=models.CharField(max_length=4,blank=True,null=True)
   SekolahKet=models.TextField(blank=True,null=True)
```

views.py

```
def tambah_siswa(request):
   form = datasiswa(request.POST)
   form2 = riwayatsekolah(request.POST)
   FormSet2 = inlineformset_factory(DataPribadiSiswa, RiwayatSekolah, extra=2, fields=('SekolahID','SiswaID_FK','SekolahNama','SekolahThMasuk','SekolahThKeluar','SekolahKet'))
   if request.method == 'POST':
       if form.is_valid():
           siswa_instance = form.save()
           form2 = FormSet2(request.POST, instance=siswa_instance)
           if form2.is_valid():
               form2.save()
           return redirect('index')
   else:
       formall={}
       formall['form'] = datasiswa()
       formall['form2'] = riwayatsekolah()
   return render(request, 'siswa/tambah_siswa.html', formall)
```

and this is my template

```
<form action="" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
<table >
    {{ form2.management_form }}
    {{ form2.as_table }}
</table>
</form>
```

How to insert multiple row from form2 into database? when i run this code, it just insert one row.

Comment: you can create object of  model which is mapped with you form2 and put the field from form2.cleaned_data['field'] and saved the object.

Comment: Where i put `form2.cleaned_data['field']` @vivekpradhan?

Comment: modelobject.field = form2.cleaned_data['field'] and finally modelobject.save()

Comment: is  field from `form2.cleaned_data['field']` name from html code or field name from model?

Comment: field name  from form

Comment: It's not working @vivekpradhan, it still insert just one row only the last row

Comment: you want to add multiple row(fields) from form2, right?

Comment: yes right @vivekpradhan

Comment: share the new code, what you wrote

Comment: I have edited my views.py @vivekpradhan

Comment: you have to do the same for other fields

Comment: RiwayatSekolah.field = form2.cleaned_data['SekolahThMasuk'], RiwayatSekolah.field = form2.cleaned_data['SekolahThKeluar'], make sure that the .field is properly mapped with corresponding model field.

Comment: i get this error `unbound method save() must be called with RiwayatSekolah instance as first argument (got nothing instead)`, i think it must be save in Sekolah_instance, isn't it?

Comment: create object of model in which you want to store the data.then use the dot operator eg . YourModel(field1=form2.cleaned_data['SekolahThKeluar'],).save(), easiest way to do.

Comment: i get this error `'field1' is an invalid keyword argument for this function`

Comment: Field1 is only example, use your respective field name from model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simplify working with related objects you can use  [Inline formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets)

You can implement it this way:

```
from django.forms import inlineformset_factory
FormSet2 = inlineformset_factory(DataPribadiSiswa, RiwayatSekolah, extra=2)
```

Now in view try this:

```
def tambah_siswa(request):
    form = datasiswa(request.POST or None)
    FormSet2 = inlineformset_factory(DataPribadiSiswa, RiwayatSekolah, extra=2, fields=('SekolahID','SiswaID_FK','SekolahNama','SekolahThMasuk','SekolahThKeluar','SekolahKet'))
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            siswa_instance = form.save()
            form2 = FormSet2(request.POST or None, instance=siswa_instance) 
            if form2.is_valid():
                form2.save()
            return redirect('index')
    form2 = FormSet2(request.POST or None) 
    formall={}
    formall['form'] = form
    formall['form2'] = form2
    return render(request, 'siswa/tambah_siswa.html', formall)
```

And in template:

```
{{ form2.management_form }}
{{ form2.as_table }}
```

or

```
{{ form2.management_form }}    
{% for frm in form2 %}
    {{ frm.as_table }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: @Gusan can you show models, view and template code?

Comment: When i run it i get this error `Calling modelformset_factory without defining 'fields' or 'exclude' explicitly is prohibited`, after i change  like this `FormSet2 = inlineformset_factory(DataPribadiSiswa, RiwayatSekolah, extra=2, fields=('SekolahID','SiswaID_FK','SekolahNama','SekolahThMasuk','SekolahThKeluar','SekolahKet'))` and click input button i get this error `[u'ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with']`

Comment: @Gusan try to add {{ form2.management_form }} before {{ form2.as_table }} in template.

Comment: still not working @neverwalkaloner, i still get the same error `[u'ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with']`

Comment: @Gusan did you add {% csrf_token %} before {{ form2.management_form }}? BTW please show template code with formset added.

Comment: @Gusan can you show how view and template look after changes?

Comment: @Gusan updated my answer. The problem is you pass into the context `formall['form2'] = riwayatsekolah()` simple form riwayatsekolah not formset form2